# diff - difference in files

Tags: shell, diff

I have made program That outputs a text file. I also have a  model file which shows me, how its supposed to look. My trouble is I cant find the difference in those files, but diff(in bash) command found some. Can any1 tell what is the difference in those files and how can i fix it.
BTW I checked both files with vim (hidden characters enabled) and both have same endfile symbol $.
I checked with `diff ble.txt bla.txt`

```
  1c1
< TEXT: hi
---
> TEXT: hi

\ No newline at end of file
```

here are the files 
http://www56.zippyshare.com/v/55059487/file.html?
thx for help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diff is telling you the problem: one of the files does not end with a newline. When editing in vim do

```
:set fileformat=unix
```

and save.

You can see the difference with

```
cat -e ble.txt; cat -e bla.txt
```

or

```
od -c ble.txt; od -c bla.txt
```